# Fixed positions messes up the width

Tags: css, html, css-position

I have a HTML5 audio player in a div. I have set its width to 100%. I wanted to fix the player at the top when scrolled so I fixed it's position. The problem is when I do that, the player width overflows the container.

Below is my code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <audio src="#" controls></audio>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width : 350px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #BADA55;
}

audio {
    width: 100%;
    /*position: fixed;*/
}
```

I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfQ5K/1/) to demonstrate the issue. Its currently in the state which I want it to look like. Un-comment the `position: fixed;` to see the problem.

Can anyone please tell me what I should do to make it stay fixed with the correct width?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can try with

```
width:inherit;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vfQ5K/2/

Comment: Nice but does not work when the width is a percentage (width:100%; for example).

Answer (score 0):

Need to wrap the audio element and apply the css to the wrapper. I updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfQ5K/3/).

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="audioWrap">
    <audio arc="#" controls></audio>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then CSS:

```
#container {
  width : 350px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #BADA55;
  position: relative;
}

.audioWrap {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Note, if you are fixing it's position inside the container, you may want to add 'position: relative' to the container. I went ahead and added that to the jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the audio player needs to completely fit the width of the main container.

Comment: @iblazevic's answer seems to work. I tested it the fixed positioning [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EMZsM/).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```css
width: -webkit-fill-available;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `width: 100%;` with **`width: inherit;`**

```css
#container {
    width : 350px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #BADA55;
}

audio {
    width: inherit;
    position: fixed;
   
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <audio src="#" controls></audio>
</div>
```

When you set `position: fixed`, the element is positioned relative to the viewport.

By using `width: inherit`, you allow the `<audio>` element to inherit the width of its parent container, which ensures it stays within the container and doesn't exceed its boundaries.

Therefore, in your case, applying `position: fixed` to the  element and using `width: inherit` is sufficient to keep the element within the parent container and maintain its width.

Comment: So... almost 10Y later [after this already posted answer in 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19583446/383904)

Comment: LoL. Yeah, it just appeared in my review queues. 

I just started to care for the questions that I am able to answer.

Comment: This answer indeed provides more context than the currently answered one, but... anyways, PS: with 2000rep points you can also edit the existing ones.